# How to calculate the sliding difference in KQL?

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics

I have a table that has an accumulated value (number of reads since the SQL server started). I want to calculate the difference (delta) between two adjacent rows and display that in a chart.

Example:

Values in table:
`1, 2, 3, 5`

Values which should appear in the chart:
`1, 1, 1, 2`

My current query is this one, but it does not calculate the difference:

```
customMetrics
| where name == "sqlserver_database_io_reads"
| extend Database = strcat(tostring(customDimensions["sql_instance"]), ".", tostring(customDimensions["database_name"]))
| summarize ["IO Reads"] = avg(value) by Database, bin(timestamp, 5m)
| render timechart
```

How can I calculate the delta for the value column?

Comment: The request is not clear. Please provide a data sample that match your code.

Comment: There is an example with data above: if the table contains the rows `1, 2, 3, 5`, I need the output `1, 1, 1, 2` which is `1-0=1, 2-1=1, 3-2=1, 5-3=2 `.

Comment: Your call. Answer posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
datatable(x:int)[1, 2, 3, 5]
| order by x asc
| project delta = x - prev(x, 1, 0)
```

| delta |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 2 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA0tJLAHCpJxUjQqrzLwSzWhDHQUjHQVjHQXTWF6uGoX8opTUIoWkSoUKhcTiZJBIQVF%20VmpyiUJKak5JooItUEIXKJZaplGhowDUbKAJALcizbhTAAAA)